# Styling ActionBar Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-styles

I'm attempting to change the colors on my ActionBar Tabs to match the colors used in my app.  I've been following the blog post here: http://blog.alwold.com/2013/08/28/styling-tabs-in-the-android-action-bar/ which is very helpful.  However when setting up the theme in Step 1 I can't find the correct  value for the parent attribute.  The website lists "Theme.Sherlock", but I'm not using ActionBarSherlock, so that doesn't apply.

My XML is as follows:

```
<style name="PropertyApp" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/PropertyApp.ActionBar.Tab</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/FindMyTrain.ActionBar.Tab</item>
</style>

<style name="PropertyApp.ActionBar.Tab">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

No matter what I use for the parent style in the top style definition, I get an error that "No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarTabStyle'".  Also, I'm told that the symbol "PropertyApp.ActionBar.Tab" cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are specifying the `Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView` parent style for your main `PropertyApp` style.

You will need to put that in your `PropertyApp.ActionBar.Tab` style.

Then put the main parent theme for `PropertyApp` like Theme.Holo.

```
<style name="PropertyApp" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/PropertyApp.ActionBar.Tab</item>
</style>

<style name="PropertyApp.ActionBar.Tab" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

The naming of the parent styles will also depend on which API levels you are targeting. AppCompat for example if you are using that.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs) on changing the tab backgrounds.

Comment: I appreciate the edits, it makes your answer even clearer yet.  Thank you.

Comment: @MrWizard54 yeah sorry haha, I was sort of wrong in what I was saying before. Plus I made it more complicated than it needed to be.